# Which materials make up a Commercial Satellite?

Tags: the-moon, communication-satellite

I'm writing a story based on the premise that an already-existing moon base is used to mine, construct, and launch a bunch of commercial satellites to GTO (the lunar surface is way "closer" to GTO than Earth's surface, in terms of delta-v, making launches vastly cheaper).

My question is, specifically, which metals/materials make up a commercial satellite, and in roughly what proportions?  From there, I can determine what can be mined from the moon, and what must be imported from Earth (at insane expense).

Thanks!

Comment: Aluminum and silicon (plus impurities)...

Comment: Magnesium and titanium may be used too. But pure metals are often less strong than a carefully chosen alloy of several metals, for instance alloys like [duralumin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duralumin) used for airframes and spaceships.